# #1215 - Não pode acrescentar uma restrição de chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-estrangeira

Boa noite,

Não estou conseguindo descobrir o porque do erro#1215. Estou a algumas horas e ainda não consegui descobrir. Alguém consegue me dar um help? Obrigado!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imovelweb`.`cadastro` (
      `id_cadastro` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `empresa` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `cnpj` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `razao_social` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `endereco` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `numero` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `complemento` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `bairro` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `cidade` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `estado` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `cep` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_cadastro`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imovelweb`.`imoveis` (
      `id_imoveis` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `titulo` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      `descricao` LONGTEXT NULL,
      `area_util` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `area_cons` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `quartos` INT NULL,
      `banheiros` INT NULL,
      `vagas` INT NULL,
      `logo` BLOB NULL,
      `valor` DOUBLE NULL,
      `id_cadastro` INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id_imoveis`, `id_cadastro`),
       CONSTRAINT `fk_imoveis_cadastro`
       FOREIGN KEY (`id_cadastro`)
       REFERENCES `webimoveis`.`cadastro` (`id_cadastro`)
       ON DELETE NO ACTION
       ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Tem certeza de que é isto: REFERENCES `webimoveis`.`cadastro` (`id_cadastro`) ou deveria ser: REFERENCES `imovelweb`.`cadastro` (`id_cadastro`)? Talvez o nome do BD errado?

Comment: REFERENCES `webimoveis`.`cadastro` (`id_cadastro`). Esqueci de alterar o nome do bd. Agora funcionou. Obrigado!